# CamStudio Recorder 2.6 Reports WaveoutGetSelectionControl() failed?

Tags: screencasts, camstudio

I'm running CamStudio v2.6 r294 on Windows 7 Ultimate, and when I go to `Options->Record Audio from Speakers` I receive the error `WaveoutGetSelectionControl() failed`

I also get this error when I go to `Options->Audio Options->Audio Options for Speakers` and click `Auto Search`, and this same thing occurs for every `Sound Card Device` that I try to use.

[image: CamStudio in the Flesh]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions may work for other releases of CamStudio and Windows.

CamStudio 2.7.2 and Windows 7:

Start-->Settings-->Control Panel-->Sound-->Recording

Right-click on list of sound sources and select "Show Disabled Devices"

Right-click on "Stereo Mix" and select "Set as Default Device"

On CamStudio, Options: if unchecked, check "Record Audio from Microphone"

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I19t9UZnuN4).

2.Open sounds click recoding tab-right click-Show Disable Devices

3.Enable Stereo Mix and right click select properties. Select Speakers under Listen Tab Click ok -ok

4.Open Cam studio under Options -Audio options - Audio Options For Microphone. Select Stereo Mix in Audio Capture Device and the recording format set that to 44.1 khz Stereo 16-bit